# How to make a VLOOKUP formula conditional in Excel?

Tags: excel

I've got a large Excel workbook with multiple worksheets and copious amounts of data. Every third sheet is an amalgam of the previous two sets. I've set up the following formula to pull the data from each worksheet, add it together, and present it in the third worksheet:

`=SUM(VLOOKUP($A7,'worksheet 1'!$A:$F,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($A7,'worksheet 2'!$A:$F,2,FALSE))`

This works as expected, unless the column A value is in one of the source worksheets but not the other. Then, I get the #N/A error with "Value not available."

What I want to do is make it so that, if the column A value is not present in the first worksheet, excel ignores that VLOOKUP request and simply pulls in the data from the second worksheet (and vice-versa for a value in the #2 but not #1).

If VLOOKUP isn't the appropriate tool to use, I can change it. I had an example sheet that I used to build this query, and that's how they put it together.

I am not an Excel expert and I've never used Access, so I'm learning as I go. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `iferror`?

Comment: As @findwindow stated wrap both vlookups with `IFERROR(...,0)`  Also a note.  If you are using the sum function you do not need the `+` but put a `,` between.  If you are using the `+` there is no reason for the `SUM()` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks - wasn't aware of the 'iferror' statement. I'll look that up and revise and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks @findwindow and Scott Craner, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using numbers, you could actually use multiple sumif statements.

I would suggest something like:

```
=SUM(SUMIF('worksheet 1'!$A:$A,$A7,'worksheet 1'!$B:$B), SUMIF('worksheet 2'!$A:$A,$A7,'worksheet 2'!$B:$B))
```

SUMIF is faster, won't look in the entire range, and if it does not find the value in A7, it will simply return 0.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Simple example. Say we have 2 sheets with a total column and we would like to get the value of that total cell:

[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

you could sum 2 `VLOOKUP` forumale, or you could use `SUMIF` as follows:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A$7,Sheet1!$B:$B),SUMIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,$A$7,Sheet2!$B:$B))
```

The above is simply saying: Look for the value in cell A7 in the range $A:$A in sheet1 and return what's in the same row in the range $B:$B, and do the same in sheet2, then sum them both.

Note that `SUMIF` will actually sum all the resutls in a range, so if you have 2 totals in Sheet1!$A:$A then it will sum them both up. In a way this is the opposite of what `VLOOKUP` will do: it will stop once the first row containing the value is found. `SUMIF` won't stop.

The desired result in the example above is 208 and that's what you shall get.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SUMIF, but if it only works on numbers, I'm not sure it would work in this situation? The value in A2 is actually text (a country name), and the formula created to find the same country name in a different sheet, then pull the related data.  The data being pulled and added is numbers, but the lookup is for text.

Comment: @LMKWeb: if the desired output is a text, SUMIF won't work. If the desired output is numbers, the above example would work. I have updated the answer with a demo. Note that in some cases where the numbers are stored as text the formula won't work.